# why map with condition return always value

Tags: dictionary, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm using rxjs map to retrive data in firestore like this:

```js
  getArtists(): Observable<DocumentData> {
    const users$ = this.firestore.collection('/Users').get()
    users$.subscribe((users) => {
      users.docs.map(user => user.data().artistName !== "" && user.data().role === 'ARTIST')
    });
    return users$;
  }
```

but when i'm getting value like this :

```js
this.userService.getArtists().subscribe(
      (userDocs) => {
        userDocs.docs.map((user) => {
          this.artists.push(user.data());
          console.log(this.artists)
          this.record = this.artists.length;
        })
      });
```

it's return always the user when the artistName is equals to `""` and role is not equals to `'ARTIST'`.
why ?

thank's everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to map data in a `map` operator instead of a `subscription` and return a value in as a pipe.
Unfortunately, in your code isn't clear what and when you want to filter, why a `user` is in `users.docs` when it tend to be a `doc`.

Please check an example below and consider updating your question with more info.

```js
import {filter, map} from 'rxjs/opreators';

  getArtists(): Observable<DocumentData> {
    return this.firestore.collection('/Users').get().pipe( // <- use pipe
       map(users => {
          // here some changes in users if we need.
          return users;
       }),
    ),
    filter(users => {
      returns true; // or false if we don't want to emit this value.
    }),
  }
```

Comment: i resolve like this : getArtists(): Observable<DocumentData> {
     return this.firestore.collection('/Users').get().pipe(
      map((users) => users.docs.filter(user => user.data().artistName !== "" && user.data().role === 'ARTIST').map(user => user)
    ))
  }

Comment: but how can i get value of pipe in my component ?

Comment: the same as you do in your code via `subscribe` = `this.userService.getArtists().subscribe`. The goal is to subscribe only when you need data to display somewhere. If you need to filter / transform / join etc - use pipes. The solution in your comment is fine, but `.map(user => user)` is redundant, it doesn't change anything.